# Discrete random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

You're given a discrete random vector:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} {xi/yj}
 & \text{0} & \text{1} \\ \hline
\text{-1} & 0 & {1/4} \\ \hline
\text{0} & {1/2} & 0 \\ \hline
\text{1} & 0 & {1/4} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

You need to find the correlation $corr(X,Y)$.

This is how I did it:

1. I found the expected values EX and EY, $EX = 0, EY = {1/2}$.
2. Found the expected value $E(XY) = 0$
3. Found the $cov(X, Y) = E(XY) - EX*EY = 0$
4. Found that $corr(X,Y) = 0$, because cov(X, Y) is 0.

Now, because I don't have an answer, I am doubting myself, hence why I turned here. I want to know that is the answer I got actually correct.

Comment: Yes it looks good.